# making a wider dataframe using factor columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

ok, so this one is kind of long, I have a couple huge dataframes that I'm trying to make wider and eventually merge. I want to merge and group by Year and county.

I have a couple of columns with factors that I'm trying to spread. essentially I want to take factor x,y,z and make them columns, x,y, and z. **I have an example below**.  Additionally, I have a few columns that are numeric that I would like to sum by group. 
I've tried to provide an example and some reproducible code to work with hopefully that's enough, but please let me know if there's anything I can do to make things easier/clearer, and thanks so much for the help!

```
 YR<-as.factor( c(2019,2018,2019,2019,2018,2018,2019,2019,2018))
    STATE<-as.factor( c("CA","MA","KY","KY","CA","MA","KY","KY","CA"))
    COUNTY<-as.factor( c("C1","M1","K1","K2","C1","M2","K1","K2","C1"))
    CANCER<-as.factor(c("Cervical","Lung","Prostate","Breast","Cervical","Breast","Prostate","Prostate","Lung"))
    rand_fact<-as.factor(c("rf1","rf2","rf3","fr4","fr5","rf2","rf3","fr4","fr5"))
    rand_num<-as.numeric(c(4,3,5,7,3,5,3,24,9))
    rand_chr<-as.character(c("a","d","r","e","g","y","r","e","k"))
    TEST_DR<-data.frame(YR,STATE,COUNTY,CANCER,rand_fact,rand_num,rand_chr)
    rm(YR,STATE,COUNTY,CANCER,rand_chr,rand_num,rand_fact)
    > print(TEST_DR)
        YR STATE COUNTY   CANCER rand_fact rand_num rand_chr
    1 2018    CA     C1 Cervical       fr5        3        g
    2 2018    CA     C1     Lung       fr5        9        k
    3 2018    MA     M1     Lung       rf2        3        d
    4 2018    MA     M2   Breast       rf2        5        y
    5 2019    CA     C1 Cervical       rf1        4        a
    6 2019    KY     K1 Prostate       rf3        5        r
    7 2019    KY     K1 Prostate       rf3        3        r
    8 2019    KY     K2   Breast       fr4        7        e
    9 2019    KY     K2 Prostate       fr4       24        e
    

#Idealy the output will look like below with rows grouped by YR then COUNTY

    TEST_DR<-arrange(.data = TEST_DR,YR,COUNTY)
    YR<-as.factor( c(2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019))
    STATE<-as.factor( c("CA","MA","MA","CA","KY","KY"))
    COUNTY<-as.factor( c("C1","M1","M2","C1","K1","K2"))
    Cervical<-as.numeric(c(1,0,0,1,0,0))
    Lung <-as.numeric(c(1,1,0,0,0,0))
    Prostate<-as.numeric(c(0,0,0,0,2,1))
    Breast<-as.numeric(c(0,0,1,0,0,1))
    
    TEST_DR2 <-data.frame(YR,STATE,COUNTY,Cervical,Lung,Prostate,Breast)
    rm(YR,STATE,COUNTY,Cervical,Lung,Prostate,Breast)
    > print(TEST_DR2)

        YR STATE COUNTY Cervical Lung Prostate Breast rand_num
    1 2018    CA     C1        1    1        0      0       12
    2 2018    MA     M1        0    1        0      0        3
    3 2018    MA     M2        0    0        0      1        5
    4 2019    CA     C1        1    0        0      0        4
    5 2019    KY     K1        0    0        2      0        8
    6 2019    KY     K2        0    0        1      1       31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `count()` and {tidyr} `spread()`

```r
YR <- as.factor( c(2019,2018,2019,2019,2018,2018,2019,2019,2018))
STATE <- as.factor( c("CA","MA","KY","KY","CA","MA","KY","KY","CA"))
COUNTY <- as.factor( c("C1","M1","K1","K2","C1","M2","K1","K2","C1"))
CANCER <- as.factor(c("Cervical","Lung","Prostate","Breast","Cervical","Breast","Prostate","Prostate","Lung"))
rand_fact <- as.factor(c("rf1","rf2","rf3","fr4","fr5","rf2","rf3","fr4","fr5"))
rand_num <- as.numeric(c(4,3,5,7,3,5,3,24,9))
rand_chr <- as.character(c("a","d","r","e","g","y","r","e","k"))
TEST_DR <- data.frame(YR, STATE, COUNTY, CANCER, rand_fact, rand_num, rand_chr)
rm(YR,STATE,COUNTY,CANCER,rand_chr,rand_num,rand_fact)

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

TEST_DR %>% 
  group_by(YR, STATE, COUNTY) %>%
  count(CANCER, rand_num = sum(rand_num)) %>%
  spread(CANCER, n, fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#> # Groups:   YR, STATE, COUNTY [6]
#>   YR    STATE COUNTY rand_num Breast Cervical  Lung Prostate
#>   <fct> <fct> <fct>     <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 2018  CA    C1           12      0        1     1        0
#> 2 2018  MA    M1            3      0        0     1        0
#> 3 2018  MA    M2            5      1        0     0        0
#> 4 2019  CA    C1            4      0        1     0        0
#> 5 2019  KY    K1            8      0        0     0        2
#> 6 2019  KY    K2           31      1        0     0        1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And for the most up-to-date {tidyverse} syntactic sugar...

```r
TEST_DR %>% 
  group_by(YR, STATE, COUNTY) %>%
  count(CANCER, rand_num = sum(rand_num)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = CANCER, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: You can also use `tidyr::replace_na` if needed 
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html

Comment: Or just add `fill = 0` to `spread`. Also, I believe that the package developers are encouraging the use of `pivot_wider` instead of `spread`.

Comment: To my knowledge there are no plans to deprecate `gather`/`spread`. But you are right, and +1 for fill.

Comment: This looks perfect, i'll try it on my larger DF. let you know  how it goes. Thanks

Can count take multiple columns or should I do multiple pipes(?) to count/sum/average the different columns?

Comment: This worked really well! thanks so much. is there a good place in the pipe to try and make an additional column that adds up all the cancer columns we just created??

Comment: I think what you want is something like `mutate(total=sum(Cervical:Prostate))` as a final step in the pipeline.

Comment: Regarding your first question -- answer is yes, count can take multiple columns. I don't think that you have enough rows.. i.e. variation in `rand_fact` within YR, STATE, COUNTY in your example to demo that, but you should be able to just add them comma-separated.

Comment: Thanks so much, this has been really helpful. I like pipes but It's been a while and the intricacies have been lost to my memory.

Comment: I've posted one more question I'd love your help on since you were so helpful and knowledgable if you have time

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of having to aggregate the `rand_num` column, you can almost directly just use `dcast` on this. Here's how I would approach it:

```
library(data.table)
# Create a vector of keys that we can use for grouping and for 
# identifying the columns for the left-hand-side of the dcast formula
keys <- c("YR", "STATE", "COUNTY")
# * melt from data.table expects a data.table, so use either setDT or
#   as.data.table to convert your data.frame to a data.table
# * .N creates a count by the grouping variables. CANCER has been
#   added since we want to count the number of instances. It will
#   create a new column named "N" in the data
as.data.table(TEST_DR)[, list(rand_num, .N), c(keys, "CANCER")][
  # Sum the rand_num variable by the grouping variable
  , rand_num := sum(rand_num), keys][
    # Go from long to wide using dcast. 
    # * ... on the left-hand-side of the formula says to use all
    #   of the unspecified variables
    # * ~ CANCER says that the values from the CANCER column should
    #   become the new column names
    # * value.var = "N" says to fill in the combination of LHS and
    #   RHS with values from the N column
    , dcast(.SD, ... ~ CANCER, value.var = "N")]
#      YR STATE COUNTY rand_num Breast Cervical Lung Prostate
# 1: 2018    CA     C1       12      0        1    1        0
# 2: 2018    MA     M1        3      0        0    1        0
# 3: 2018    MA     M2        5      1        0    0        0
# 4: 2019    CA     C1        4      0        1    0        0
# 5: 2019    KY     K1        8      0        0    0        2
# 6: 2019    KY     K2       31      1        0    0        1
```

"data.table" commands can be chained (similar to using pipes) by just passing the result of one operation to the next operation. For example, `as.data.table(df)[, do_something][, do_something_else][, do_even_more]`.

Comment: wish you could walk me through this in person cause I am not following....
keys sets the columns that don't change in the spread.... what are all the brackets doing?

Comment: @JasonDeutsch, I've added some comments to the code. Hopefully it makes things a bit clearer. The additional square brackets are just passing the results from one operation along to the next step. You can optionally create intermediate "data.tables" rather than just doing it all as one long command.

Comment: huh!! I've never seen as.data.table used. usually I've seen as.data.frame used, That ability to chain similar to pipes is fascinating though!! your comments helped clarify a ton. so thank you for that extra work.  I'm still a little confused by the bit with the list function but I'll have to come back and ask you about that at some later date unfortunately.  Thanks so much for the help. learned a lot!

Comment: if you have time I posted a new question that I think you would probably have a solution to. please and thankyou!